# How to dual boot with win 10 on Motherboard with UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am kind of new to Linux.
I just built a desktop using ASUS Prime Z370-A motherboard with 256GB NVME hard drive, and installed windows 10 Pro (Demo version, as I have not entered the key for it). I allocated 30GB for linux, and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it (with No swap space since I have 16 GB DDR).

While installing Ubuntu, I opted for 'Something else' and selected the 30GB free space as my root, and formatted it ext4. Left the 'Device for booth loader installation' option as is.

My issue is, every time I have to boot into Ubuntu, I have to go to UEFI BIOS 'boot Priority'. I was hoping to see a grub loader giving me an option to select windows or Ubuntu.

Looks like BIOS - UEFI is getting in the way for me, or Grub is not used here ? 
Thanks and regards

Comment: did you install Ubuntu in Legacy/BIOS mode? I recommend you run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to generate an info summary (don't let it do the repair yet, just get the info link and [edit] it into your question). Then we will see what you have installed where. Hard to diagnose the problem without knowing that

Comment: Edit the question and post the output of the command: `ls /sys/firmware/efi`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your machine have UEFI. Ok, if your machine have UEFI configuration, first make sure to use **Rufus**(UEFI compatible) to make a bootable USB stick (if you are using usb to install it) and select the GPT partition scheme. 
Please have a look at this link (https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/), they have got valuable info and provided details procedure (more or less the procedure is almost same).

If after installing Ubuntu, you boot directly in Windows, check in UEFI settings for changing the boot order. If you see no option to set the boot to Ubuntu, you need to fix it from within Windows. When you are in Windows desktop, hover the mouse in left corner, right click and select administrator’s command prompt. Then run the following command:
(  bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi  )

This should make the Grub default and hence you can access both Ubuntu and Windows from it.

Note: In the grub menu, if you can't find the Windows 10 boot, loader then select the advanced option (which is just below Ubuntu option in Grub menu) and press "Enter" and then run Ubuntu in recovery mode. Then there you will find a menu and select the update grub option. It will find the Win 10 boot loader. 
Hope this will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Debajyoti, I installed Ubuntu using USB and I used Etcher for it.<br> Planning to install windows 10 Home and will do Linux again.